# QGIS plugin error with PyArmor

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, security

My Python project works fine when I include it as a QGIS 3.28.6 plugin. I have also successfully used PyArmor to obfuscate the Python files in PyCharm, however that causes me to get some errors in QGIS when I try to install my plugin.

I put the **pyarmor_runtime_000000** folder into `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Lib\pyarmor_runtime_000000` resolving the first error I encountered, but I am not sure how to resolve the below new error.

This code:

```
# Pyarmor 8.2.0 (trial), 000000, 2023-05-18T12:12:16.207637
for suffix in '', '_a1', '_a2', '_a3':
    try:
        __pyarmor__ = __import__('pyarmor_runtime' + suffix,
                                 globals(), locals(),
                                 ('__pyarmor__',),
                                 0).__pyarmor__
        break
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        pass
else:
    raise ModuleNotFoundError('no pyarmor_runtime extension found')
```

Results in this error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'project-three-protected' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: no pyarmor_runtime extension found 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\project-three-protected\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .QGISProject import QGISProject
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\project-three-protected\QGISProject.py", line 4, in 
    from pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\pyarmor_runtime_000000\__init__.py", line 14, in 
    raise ModuleNotFoundError('no pyarmor_runtime extension found')
ModuleNotFoundError: no pyarmor_runtime extension found


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.28.6-Firenze Firenze, 868c9fa03b 

Python Path:
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\
C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass82\etc\python
C:\Users\xxx\Documents
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python39.zip
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```